# What does 'cathode-row' mean?

Tags: led, display

"The MAX6960–MAX6963 are compact cathode-row display drivers"
What does cathode-row mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think of a matrix of LEDs (8*8) having rows and columns, where all the cathodes are linked in a row and all the anodes are linked in a column. 
This range of ICs will drive such a matrix with no other components (apart from a microprocessor etc.). 
I realise that the the terminology of rows vs columns is arbitrary.
The terminology exists to help to understand which pins to connect up, the pictures shown and also how to send data.

Answer (score 3):

An 8-row by 16-column, cathode-row driver will at any given time drive exactly one of the 8 row wires low, while driving a program-selectable subset (none, some, or all) of the column drivers high.  An anode-row driver would drive one of eight wires high, while driving selected columns low.